# Generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I don't know how to give this a better title as I don't really know what this pattern is called in Java.

Right now I have a method with this signature:

```
public Directory getDirectory(Class<? extends Directory> type) { ... }
```

And you call it like this:

```
MyDirectory directory = (MyDirectory)getDirectory(MyDirectory.class);
```

The constraint on the type ensures that `MyDirectory` must derive from `Directory`.

What I really want to do is avoid the cast and reduce the amount of code required.  In C# you could say:

```
MyDirectory directory = getDirectory<MyDirectory>();
```

Is there a way to do this or something similar in Java?  I haven't coded any Java since version 1.4!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public <T extends Directory> T getDirectory(Class<T> type) { ... }

MyDirectory directory = getDirectory(MyDirectory.class);
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I had exactly that minus the `T` as the return type.  I figured the braces themselves were the return type.  They're actually just a constraint then?

Comment: @Drew: The `<T extends Directory>` defines the type parameter `T` for the generic method... you have to have that declaration for any generic method even if you aren't giving it specific bounds (like `extends Directory`).

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could avoid the cast by changing the method itself to be generic:

```
public <T extends Directory> T getDirectory(Class<T> type)
```

and then:

```
MyDirectory directory = getDirectory(MyDirectory.class);
```

Here you're using type inference from the argument to determine the type of `T`.

But you do have to pass the `Class<T>` in, as otherwise type erasure will kick in and the method won't know the type to create an instance of :(

For more details of type erasure and just about everything else to do with Java generics, see Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).